# Subsequences of $f_n(x)=x^2/(x^2+(1-nx)^2)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Consider the sequence of functions

$$f_n(x)=\frac{x^2}{x^2+(1-nx)^2}$$

I've been able to show that the sequence a) is bounded, b) is pointwise convergent to $0$.

> But how can I show that no subsequence of $\{f_n\}$ can converge
>   uniformly?

Thanks in advance for any solution or hint!

Answer (score 1):

Since  $f_n(1/n)=1$ then $f_n$ does not converge uniformly to $f=0$ in any open interval $I$ that contains $0$. In fact for $n$ sufficiently large $1/n\in I$ and 
$$\sup_{x\in I}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\sup_{x\in I}|f_n(x)|\geq |f(1/n)|=1 \not\to 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\exists $ a subsequence of $f_n$ which converges uniformly say $f_{n_k}=g_k$(say).

Then by Weierstrass M test the sequence $M_k=\sup_{x\in \Bbb R}|g_k|\to 0 $ as $k\to \infty $.

Now $g_k=\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+(1-kx)^2}$ for a fixed $k$ changes its sign at $x=0$ where it attains a minima(compute $g_k^{'}(x)=0$ and $g_k^{''}(0)<0$)

Hence $M_k$ never tends to $0$.

Thus no subsequence converges